# Use a running container in a jenkins pipeline (jenkins container)

Tags: git, docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

currently I am setting up a CI/CD-Toolchain with docker and jenkins and some other tools.

However, my jenkins-pipeline now runs, so that everytime a job is triggered, a new container is build out of a local image.
That is not bad, but at this rate, the container have to be build "from scratch" every time, which costs a few seconds.

My approach now is, to try to reuse an already existing container to perform the same action again, but with another git checkout.

However, because I am using a scripted pipeline with git-checkout, I always build a new container.
I do not want to create a script on my host machine or anything that just runs the existing container, because I have to update the container eventually.
I want to use the existing container out of the jenkins scripted pipeline.
Is that possible?

My pipeline till now:

```
node {    
   checkout([
       $class: 'GitSCM',
       branches: [[name: '*/master']],
       doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
       extensions: [[$class: 'GitLFSPull'],
       [$class: 'CleanCheckout']],
       submoduleCfg: [],
       userRemoteConfigs: [
           [credentialsId: //blank :) //,
           url: //blank :) // ]]]
    )
    
    
    def myImage = docker.build("vectorcast")
    myImage.inside{
        sh label: '', script: 'sh /vcast/run-tests.sh'
    }
}
```

For explanation purposes:
First I check out of a git project, because I need the saved files to build the image (installer etc.)
Then I build a container out of this image and perform some test, which are triggered by the sh.

Thanks for help, I appreciate it

Comment: What part is taking multiple seconds; rebuilding the image (which needs to be redone whenever the source changes, and Jenkins is a good place to do that) or starting the container (the `myImage.inside` setup)?  The container startup shouldn't usually take multiple seconds, but you can run multiple pipeline commands inside the `myImage.inside` block if it'd help you.

Comment: Maybe focusing on the time was not right. We want to reuse existing containers to safe space and so on.
But is this even something we should do or would you suggest to build a "clean" container every time, even if the image did not change?

Comment: Containers are supposed to be lightweight.  In Jenkins in particular it's straightforward to run multiple steps inside a container so you may as well, but in general, multiple `docker run` steps that do a single thing are fine.